# On Internet Explorer, window.opener is lost after submitting form to a different URL and then coming back

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, popup

There is a popup window that submits its form to a third party url on load.
The user selects his address using the third party service.
When the user clicks on the finish button of the third party service, the third party service redirects the user back to my original popup url.

The source code of the popup.jsp looks like this.

```
    <% 

    String inputYn = request.getParameter("inputYn"); 
    String roadFullAddr = request.getParameter("roadFullAddr"); 
    String roadAddrPart1 = request.getParameter("roadAddrPart1"); 
    String roadAddrPart2 = request.getParameter("roadAddrPart2"); 
    String engAddr = request.getParameter("engAddr"); 
    String jibunAddr = request.getParameter("jibunAddr"); 
    String zipNo = request.getParameter("zipNo"); 
    String addrDetail = request.getParameter("addrDetail"); 
    String admCd    = request.getParameter("admCd");
    String rnMgtSn = request.getParameter("rnMgtSn");
    String bdMgtSn  = request.getParameter("bdMgtSn");
%>
function init(){

        var url = location.href;
        var confmKey = "serviceKeyIssuedBytheThirdParty";
        var inputYn= "<%=inputYn%>";
        if(inputYn != "Y"){
            document.form.confmKey.value = confmKey;
            document.form.returnUrl.value = url;
            document.form.action="http://www.somethirdpartyservice.do"; 
            document.form.submit();
        }else{
             try {
                 opener.jusoCallBack("<%=roadFullAddr%>","<%=roadAddrPart1%>","<%=addrDetail%>","<%=roadAddrPart2%>","<%=engAddr%>","<%=jibunAddr%>","<%=zipNo%>", "<%=admCd%>", "<%=rnMgtSn%>", "<%=bdMgtSn%>");
            } catch (err) {
                alert(err.description || err) //or console.log or however you debug
            }
            window.close();
        }
    }
```

The javascript  `jusoCallBack` function on the parent page.

```
function jusoCallBack(roadFullAddr,roadAddrPart1,addrDetail,roadAddrPart2,engAddr, jibunAddr, zipNo, admCd, rnMgtSn, bdMgtSn){
        console.log("jusoCallBack");

        document.form.newAddress.value += roadFullAddr;

}
```

The problem is that it works just fine on Google Chrome but I get an error that says `Unable to get property 'jusoCallBack' of undefiend or null reference`.

I experimented so that the function `jusoCallBack` will be fired on the first popup window load, before it submits the form to the third party URL.
The popup window finds its opener just fine and the function `jusoCallBack` is fired.

It seems to me that, for some reason, the popup window loses the opener information after it had navigated to a third party URL.

But it works just fine on Google Chrome though. So I'm not so sure.

Is the popup window supposed to remember who the opener is even after the popup windows had navigated out to a different URL or is it normal for the popup window to lose its opener?